# How check token List with php?

Tags: php

Hello I come from Vietnam . I am doing my web3 project with php. I'm having trouble writing a complete check.php code. Can anyone help me?

```
 if (HARDCACHED_API_RESPONSE && (connected == "2" || getItem("tokenList"))) {
    console.log("NO API");
    tokenList = getItem("tokenList");
    connected = 2;
} else {
    console.log("API");
    const response = await fetch("/check.php?account=" + account, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: `token=0sx18343jksdqw`,
    });
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, i just want someone to help me write a complete .php file. Message me on telegram @tuanhungvl to see the full . I will give a small gift to thank the person who helped me